# Spring Boot application stops with Process finished with exit code 1 and SLF4J StaticLoggerBinder warning

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I've encountered an issue while trying to start my Spring Boot (v2.7.8) application. At the end of the startup sequence, it terminates abruptly and displays **`Process finished with exit code 1`**.

The startup log begins with a warning related to SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Subsequently, the initialization sequence for Tomcat and Spring Boot begins, but it seems Tomcat is stopped shortly after. The relevant logs are:

```
:: Spring Boot :: (v2.7.8)
Aug 31, 2023 11:18:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Aug 31, 2023 11:18:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
Aug 31, 2023 11:18:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Aug 31, 2023 11:18:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

I understand from the SLF4J warning that there might be a missing binding or implementation for the logger. However, I'm unsure if this is the root cause of the abrupt termination or if there's another underlying issue causing Tomcat to stop.

Here is my application.properties and log4j2.xml file contents

*`spring.datasource.username`*`="""""""""`
*`spring.datasource.password`*`="""""""""`
*`spring.datasource.driver-class-name`*`=org.postgresql.Driver`
*`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema`*`="""""""""""`
*`server.port`*`=8180`
*`logging.level.org.springframework`*`=INFO`
*`logging.level.org.springframework.web`*`=INFO`
*`logging.level.root`*`=INFO`
*`logging.level.org.hibernate`*`=ERROR`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="log/app.log"
                     filePattern="log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can guide me on potential solutions or next steps to diagnose this problem further?

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with your issue. You only have no/little logging as you have no log4j2 with slf4j integration. Do you really need log4j2 instead of the default logback?

Comment: I doubt that is the issue as well as that is probably the detection if JMX is enabled or not. Enable debug loggin (and maybe even remove log4j2 for the time being and use the default logback log configuration from Spring Boot) to get information on what is happening.

Comment: I've removed the jboss and wildfly tags as this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with either community.